# read in text file of numbers to a list without the single quotes Python

Tags: python, list, text-files

When I read in a text file of numbers:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

The list is created like:

```
dTags = ['1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8']
```

I do not want the single quotes at the beginning and end of the list, so I just want it to be like:

```
dTags = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

This is the code I am using:

```
dTags = []
with open("tagNumbersToTest.txt") as file:
    for line in file: 
        line = line.strip() #or some other preprocessing
        dTags.append(line) #storing everything in memory!

#print(dTags)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a line:

```
line = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8"
```

you can append a list of integers using:

```
dTags.append([int(x) for x in line.split(",")])
```

This will append a list such as:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Then your `dTags` will be a list of lists.  If instead you want all the lines concatenated as one list rather than a list of lists, then use `extend` instead of `append`.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it is appending a single item to a list. Your desired output contains 5 elements. One thing that you can try is -

```
dTags = []
with open("tagNumbersToTest.txt") as file:
    for line in file: 
        dTags.extend(line.split(','))
```

Output -

```
['1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4', ' 5']
```

To get all the integer values instead of string then you can add the below line provided all the elements are of int datatype.

```
dTags_list = [int(i) for i in dTags]
```

Output -

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

To summarize your code -

```
    dTags = []
    with open("tagNumbersToTest.txt") as file:
        for line in file: 
            dTags.extend([int(i) for i in line.split(',')])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try
(assuming you 1 line of text in your file)

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
  nums = [int(x) for x in f.readline().strip().split(',')]
  print(nums)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert string to Python code, you can use `eval(list(line))` even if I don't recommend it for security reasons.

```
dTags = []
with open("tagNumbersToTest.txt") as file:
    for line in file: 
        line = line.strip()
        dTags.append(list(eval(line)))
```

`dTags` will be a list of lists but you can then manipulate it or modify the text file to get the output you want.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: was able to get it working using another answer, thank you though